# Delegate method to segue in tableviewcell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I have a delegate method where if I press a button in the tableview, it should segue to another view controller and pass along data but it doesn't seem to work.

```
func goToVC(uid: String) { //delegate method
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showVC", sender: self) //Do I need this
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showVC", sender: self)
    self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showVC" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let guestVC = segue.destination as! GuestViewController
            guestVC.ref = userArray[indexPath.row].ref
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    // set the cell's delegate in the data source
    // pass the object to the cell from the data source
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        cell.mainViewControllerDelegate = self
        cell.object = someArray[indexPath.row]

    }

    // this is the method that gets called by the cell through the delegate
    func pushToViewController(object: YourDataObject) {

        let destination = SomeViewController()
        destination.object = object
        navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)

    }

}

class TheTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // create a delegate and a data object
    var mainViewControllerDelegate: MainViewController?
    var object: YourDataObject?

    // this is the method that gets called when the button in the cell is tapped
    @objc func buttonAction() {

        mainViewControllerDelegate?.pushToViewController(object: object)

    }

}
```

I highly recommend that beginners do not use Interface Builder. The less you use it early, the quicker you will understand more. Interface Builder is fool's gold for beginners.

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting a black screen (but no error) when it redirects to the new view controller. What's the best solution to solve this?

Comment: It appears you have the delegate hooked up properly. First confirm that by removing `navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)` and just printing to console `print("great success")`. If the delegate is indeed operating, push the view controller how you normally do it in Interface Builder. The example I gave is for programmatic apps but none of the concepts change.

Comment: Hmm...the delegate seems to be working as it prints out "great success". Any other way that I push it to another view controller within the delegate?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need delegate method here. Delegate method can be used if you need to pass the value from the child view controller.

What you are doing is exactly right. Make sure you set the segue identifier in the story board correctly.

And one more thing dont set your table IBOutlet as default `tableView` try setting a name apt for that table like `toDoTable`, so it will easy to debug.